# Improve performance of difference between elements block

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a rather simple block that obtains the absolute valued difference between two selected elements from two arrays.

```
import numpy as np

# Input data with proper format.
N_bb, N_cc = np.random.randint(1e5), np.random.randint(1e5)
bb = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N_bb)
cc = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N_cc)

# My actual code repeats this process ~500 times.
all_ds = []
for _ in range(500):

    # An index into cc for each element in bb.
    idx_into_cc = np.random.randint(0, len(cc), len(bb))

    # This is the block I need to make faster.
    aa = []
    for i, b in enumerate(bb):
        aa.append(abs(b - cc[idx_into_cc[i]]))
    d = np.median(aa)

    # Use 'd' before the next iteration, and store the result.
    all_ds.append(some_func(d))
```

I use the absolute difference because I need positive values, I could also use a squared difference. The `bb` and `cc` arrays stay unchanged during the entire process, but `idx_into_cc` changes with each iteration.

How can I improve the performance of this code?

Comment: Maybe initialize `aa` to its full size before the beginning of the loop, then use indexing instead of `append`? I would imagine that to be more efficiently implemented under the hood.

Comment: Replace the last line with `d = np.median(np.abs(bb-cc[idx_into_cc]))` to remove the inner loop?

Comment: Ok, that was ridiculously simple. Now I'm ashamed I didn't think of that (must be I'm on my 11th hour of work...) Thank you very much Divakar, do you want to turn your cmmt into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can simply use vectorized indexing to remove the inner loop, like so -

```
d = np.median(np.abs(bb-cc[idx_into_cc]))
```

Comment: *vectorized indexing*  ? NumPy calls it as *fancy indexing* ;)  (in simple terms *indexing arrays using arrays*)